# Cannot Write to Bootcamp After Installing Paragon NTFS for Mac

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, mount, ntfs

I ran a Windows 10 operating system on the bootcamp of my macbook pro 2015. However, after using that Windows system for a few years, it failed to boot (stuck at the logo) after an upgrade. I searched online and figured out a likely cause was due to corrupted hibernation file for the Windows system (see https://www.reddit.com/r/bootcamp/comments/ewuaxa/windows_wont_boot_stuck_on_logo/fw8qwu2/), and one solution was to use Paragon NTFS for Mac to force mount the windows partition on read/write mode. However, after installing NTFS for Mac, I still could not write to the Windows Bootcamp partition (still read only as before), and I did not see any mount on read/write mode option on the NTFS for Mac software. Can anyone tell me how to mount the Bootcamp Windows partition on read/write mode using NTFS for Mac?

Comment: You could have just booted Windows installer from a flash drive. This would allow you to open a Windows Command Prompt window with read/write access to NTFS partitions. This method does not require installing third party software into macOS.

Comment: Read/Write is on by default. In the Paragon app, there's a checkbox for each drive, if you want to toggle that setting.